# How can I stop an authorized user from consuming all the bandwidth on my home network?

Tags: network, user-management, torrent

Me and my neighbours share a home network managed by me, paid for by the  landlord.

This person overloads the bandwidth on the regular, jitter spikes up to the 300s,down speed fluctuates, overall shit time.

Can't get rid of them/ block them from the network, in spite having admin access.

Is it possible to restrict their access to bandwidth / stop them from screwing the internet up for the other users?

Note: I have a second router at my disposal, Accountant by trade, little network knowledge but highly motivated.

Comment: This isn't really a security question. More of a network management question. I would check your modems documentation as you will be limited by it's capabilities. This *might* be on topic on superuser.stackexchange, but it's not on topic here.

Comment: You need a router (a wifi access point, I imagine) capable of "traffic shaping". Then you would be able to silently cap the bandwidth on a per-client basis. Some routers allow double SSID and can share bandwidth between the two, but this requires the unruly user to be restricted to their own SSID, or all the others to migrate on a new SSID withholding access, which can result in conflicts. If you feel adventurous you can maybe upgrade the AP using an OpenWRT firmware w/traffic shaping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, will look into traffic shaping.